# Checking Positivity

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory, mathematica

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql1BD.png)
I am trying to check positivity of an algebraic expressions where all the variables are positive. Using Mathematica 9.1 version I have got the result showed as follows. How to combine all these conditions?
$\begin{aligned} & \left.\left.\left.\left.\left.\left.\left.\left.\left.\left.\left(\mathrm{P} 4>0 \& 4 \mathrm{Al}^2 \mathrm{P} 4^2 \mathrm{~W} 1<\mathrm{A} 1 \mathrm{~A} 2 \mathrm{P} 4 \mathrm{P}^2\right)\right)\right)\right)|| \mid\left(\mathrm{W} 1 \neq 0 \& 4 \mathrm{Al}^2 \mathrm{P} 4^2 \mathrm{~W} 1<\mathrm{A} 1 \mathrm{~A} 2 \mathrm{P} 4 \mathrm{P} 5^2 \&((\mathrm{~A} 1>0 \& \& \mathrm{P} 4<0)||(\mathrm{A} 1<0 \& \& \mathrm{P} 4>0))\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right) \\ & \end{aligned}$

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Mathematica SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).